# Pandoc - Can you change margins and fontsize simultaneously?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

[Sample Markdown used as a Reproducible Example (GitHub hyperlink)](https://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/sample_content.html)

I pasted the markdown from the hyperlink above into the Atom text editor and saved it as a documentation.md file. I can run the following two seperate Pandoc commands and each of them works to reduce the margins on my pdf -and- increase the font size to 12 on the output pdf.

`pandoc -s -V documentation.md geometry:margin=1in -o documentation.pdf`

`pandoc -s -V documentation.md fontsize=12 -o documentation.pdf`

When I combine the two commands into the following I get the error shown below. Is there a problem in my Pandoc syntax?

`pandoc -s -V documentation.md geometry:margin=1in fontsize=12 -o documentation.pdf`

> pandoc geometry:margin=1in openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or
>   directory)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
pandoc documentation.md -V geometry:margin=1in -V fontsize:12pt -s -o documentation.pdf
```

Pandoc's [FAQs](https://pandoc.org/faqs.html#how-do-i-change-the-margins-in-pdf-output) state:

> ### How do I change the margins in PDF output?
>
> The option
>
> ```
> -V geometry:margin=1in
> ```
>
> will set the margins to one inch on each side.

Note that `geometry:margin=1in` is the value of the `-V` flag. However, you have the filename `documentation.md` between the flag and its value. Therefore, you are causing the value of the flag to be `documentation.md` and `geometry:margin=1in` is assumed to be a filename. After all, any string of text no preceded by a flag should be a filename (which explains the "No such file or directory" error).

By way of explanation, the [documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-writer-options) for the `-V` flag gives this format:

> ```
> -V KEY[:VAL]
> ```

Note that the brackets in `[:VAL]` indicate that that part is optional. So `-V KEY` is completely valid with no value, which means that `-V documentation.md` resulted in `documentation.md` being the `KEY` of the `-V` flag (with a default `VAL` of `true` as per the docs).

Admittedly, `-V geometry:margin=1in` is an especially weird case and its easy to see how one might be confused by it. In this case however, `-V` is the flag, `geometry` is the "KEY" and `margin=1in` is the "VAL". I realize that `margin=1in` looks like a `KEY=VAL`, but in this instance it is all a "VAL" on its own. Presumably, Pandoc does some further processing on it later to break the "VAL" up into its parts.

Of course, [fontsize](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex) is another variable, so you need a second `-V` flag to define that variable: `-V fontsize:12pt`.

Finally, the `-s` flag does not accept a value, so I moved it so that that is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the `-V` twice as well, directly in front of the variable options you want to set:

```
pandoc -s documentation.md -V geometry:margin=1in -V fontsize=12 -o documentation.pdf
```

see http://pandoc.org/getting-started.html and http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html